# Show list of possible values of feature in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to iterate over the possible values of a given column. I want something like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
column = data['feature']

for value in column.show_list_of_all_possible_values:
    print(value)
```

output:

```
value_0
value_1
value_2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
data['feature'].value_counts()
```

Or

```
data['feature'].unique()
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!  ❤️ This solves it

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark my answer as correct ;)